# Illegal hardware operation when running python script

Tags: python, conda, zsh, apple-m1

I've run into the following issue a couple of times and I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python3.6 hello_world.py
```

I recently got a 2020 MacBook Pro with the M1 chip and I was running into this issue when running a script with pytorch, and I thought the issue might be restricted to that, but it seems like it happens when I run any script. Specifically, I've created a conda environment using python 3.6 and installed numpy afterwards using conda. When I run the following code through VSCode:

```
import numpy as np
print("Hello world")
```

I get the above error. For reference, I'm using conda version 4.10.1. I'm not sure why this keeps popping up, so if anyone had any advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have no experience with running conda/python on the M1 but I suspect it will be helpful for you to clarify whether you are running native ARM versions of conda/python or AMD64 versions under Rosetta2.

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I directly downloaded the x86 macOS conda installer and used that.

Comment: This article might help: https://towardsdatascience.com/using-conda-on-an-m1-mac-b2df5608a141 . They are suggesting using the ARM versions though miniforge (https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge).

Comment: So I'm guessing it would be a good idea to uninstall and reinstall conda using this?

Comment: Why would you download an x86 app to a computer that does not have an x86 chip?

Comment: I'm assuming the ARM version is distinct from the x86 version right?